# How to comment and like under my name in Facebook application on my Facebook page using Facebook's Android app?

Tags: facebook

I am a moderator of a Facebook page. However, I never want to post, comment and like in the name of the page on the page itself (that's other people's role).

On the desktop website, I set to comment and like in my real name by default, but it does not affect the Android application. My comments and likes appear as the page's comments and likes.

Any solution? It's quite annoying that I cannot interact with my page when being on the phone.

Comment: Sounds more like a Facebook issue than an Android issue.

Comment: I've been trying to do the same, but apparently it is not possible...